# youtube upload api does not work from asp.net website

Tags: asp.net, api, video, upload

I've a website (Visual Web Developer 2008 Express - asp.net - vb). I want to upload movies using youtube api from my website. I posted my code below. When I click the button, I wait a while and receive 401-Unauthorized access.. error message.

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim settings As YouTubeRequestSettings = New YouTubeRequestSettings("app name", "my developer key", "my gmail", "my gmail password")

    Dim request As New YouTubeRequest(settings)
    Dim newVideo As New Video()

    newVideo.Title = "My Test Movie"
    newVideo.Tags.Add(New MediaRss.MediaCategory("Autos", YouTubeNameTable.CategorySchema))
    newVideo.Keywords = "cars, funny"
    newVideo.Description = "My description"
    newVideo.YouTubeEntry.Private = False
    newVideo.Tags.Add(New MediaRss.MediaCategory("mydevtag, anotherdevtag", YouTubeNameTable.DeveloperTagSchema))

    newVideo.YouTubeEntry.Location = New GeoRssWhere(37, -122)

    newVideo.YouTubeEntry.MediaSource = New MediaFileSource("C:\Users\Acer\Desktop\1.mov", "video/x-msvideo")
    Dim createdVideo As Video = request.Upload(newVideo)


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must specify a valid category

```
newVideo.Tags.Add(New MediaCategory("Music", YouTubeNameTable.CategorySchema))
```